# How to disassemble old Moen kitchen faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have an leaking older single-handle Moen faucet.  All the info I've found for such faucets shows a removable cap on top of the handle; removing that exposes a screw, which allows removal of the handle, etc.

This faucet doesn't have a clearly-removable cap; instead, it has a slightly inset surface on top of the faucet, which is covered with a 'Moen' sticker.  I tried gently prying on that, but it wasn't clear that it was meant to come off.

So, before pushing on and maybe defacing the surface, does anyone know how to disassemble this faucet?  Or, for that matter, what the model number would be.

Thanks

Edit: It turns out, the "Moen" thing is just a sticker.  Peel it back, and there's the screw.  No cap to pry off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: On the picture you posted that little center section where the Moen sticker is looks like it has a small recess where you can get a blade or a thin screwdriver under it or is that where you just tried to pry it before? That center cap judging by my previous experience should come out but I could be wrong. If it does that will certainly expose the screw that holds the handle on.

Comment: I had a faucet similar to this, the lever and cap that the screw holds down can be a real bear to pull still

Comment: do you know what model of this one? I have exact one and it is dripping. I can't find the model to find replacement part.

Comment: Model is on the back of the unit. If you turn the handle so its pointing away from you, you should be able to see the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drew a small black circle around the area of that tab where you can slip a utility knife point underneath of it and pop it out it should come out pretty easily.[image]

Comment: I guess this is also a correct answer...

Comment: (as per my edit to the OP) The Moen thing is just a sticker covering the screw.  It peels off.

Comment: Where you able to get the handle off of there once you got to the screw or was it really really hard to get off?

Comment: > Where you able to get the handle off of there once you got to the screw ..

Comment: user41750: Try again: ran over the clock. <br/> (and not getting this line break thing)  No problem.   After removing the screw, I pulled up on the handle and tipped it back, and it came right off. Pretty much like [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5M4feAc7Y8)

Comment: do you know what model of this one? I have exact one and it is dripping. I can't find the model to find replacement part.

Answer (score 4):

So far, everything I find online shows that the screw is certainly under the cap but no direction how specifically to remove the cap. Here is an image that I found:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had a faucet similar to this, the lever and cap that the screw holds down can be a real bear to pull still

Comment: Oooh, you even get to keep the sticker! Looked like a decal in the first pic.

Comment: do you know what model of this one? I have exact one and it is dripping. I can't find the model to find replacement part.

Answer (score 4):

The entire piece that the moen label is on pulls off. It may take a little effort, but once you have it popped off you will find the single screw underneath.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Great answer; keep 'em coming!

Comment: do you know what model of this one? I have exact one and it is dripping. I can't find the model to find replacement part.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the entire top half comes off, not just the label on top. It may pop off with a gentle prying, or with a small set screw that's exposed when the handle is raised. Shutoff the water and lift the handle to see if there are any small screws.

If you don't see any screws, feel the top label, press firmly, and see if there are any obvious indentations for a screw hole. Assuming there aren't any, give the entire top cap a gentle prying, and if it shows signs of loosening, keep working it from each side until it's free.

Answer (score 0):

the cartridge for this and many other moen kitchen faucets is a #1225 cartridge..moen has a great warranty exchange for these cartridges most hardware stores and moen dealers have replacements, bring the old for a new.

Answer (score 0):

This model is M7800 , replacement cartridge #1225 can be exchanged for free !
Thanks to Moen !
M7800 not sold anymore.